# SCCM 2016 - SCCM Agents licensing

Tags: sccm

We have a Microsoft SCCM 2016 License (MS Enterprise Agreement) Do you know whether we need to buy additional Microsoft Licenses for every SCCM Agent Client we want to install on a physical or virtual server ?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and therefor off-topic on Stack Overflow. Contact Microsoft or an authorized reseller for that type if information.

Comment: ok, now I'll remember.